# Objective c: Init method not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having trouble creating a type of my custom class `Frank`.  When I do I receive the following error:

> Class method '+initWithWorld::' not found (return type defaults to
>   'id')

My class is defined as so:

```
@interface Frank : NSObject {
    PhysicsSprite *frankSprite;
    b2Body *body;

    float weight;
}

@property (readonly) b2Body *body;

-(void)initWithWorld:(b2World *) world :(CCNode *)parent;

-(void)moveLeft;
-(void)moveRight;

@end
```

I create the object like so:

```
frank = [Frank initWithWorld:world :self];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the downvote without any feedback?

Comment: The answer has been given below, but also note that an init... method returns `id`, not `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object needs to be **allocated** first:

```
frank = [ [ Frank alloc ] initWithWorld: world :self ];
```

Your `init` method is a **member** method (width a `-` sign), meaning you need to call it on an **allocated** object, as opposed to **class** methods (with a `+` sign).

**Edit**

As pointed by @JustSid, such an `init` method must also return an object (type `id`).
So the correct method prototype is:

```
- ( id )initWithWorld: ( b2World * )world : ( CCNode * )parent;
```

The implementation should then be something like:

```
- ( id )initWithWorld: ( b2World * )world : ( CCNode * )parent;
{
    if( ( self = [ self init ] ) )
    {
        /* Your initialisation here */
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Also: The method signature says the method returns nothing, however it should return an `id`.

Comment: @JustSid Thanks for pointing this out. Added an edit in my answer. : )

Comment: Ahh this makes sense now, I had it very close to this a few times I just didnt get the alloc set up properly - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `initWithWorld::` as a class method instead of an instance method. You need

```
frank = [[Frank alloc] initWithWorld:world :self];
```

The method `+alloc` is a class method that returns a newly-allocated but uninitialized instance of the receiver (in this case, the class `Frank`). The only thing you're allowed to do with such an object is initialize it, which is done by calling the appropriate `-init` method (in this case, `-initWithWorld::`).